# pybot is not recognized as an internal or external command while running from cmd

Tags: python, robotframework

I get an issue when running the following command, in *cmd*:

```
pybot --version
```

Also given the correct environmental variable path

```
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\scripts
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\robot
```

Do you have any clues?

Comment: problem resolved by changing the robot framework version ,uninstall robot frame work from cmd type 'pip uninstall robotframework' and install the version 'pip install robot framework==3.0.2 'run the command and search for 'pybot --version'  hope this would help

Answer (score 4):

If you are using newer robotframework (like 3.1) and you really want to have an alias for `robot` (maybe because using some test runner like the one in RIDE), you can create the file `pybot.bat`at C:\Python27\Scripts with the following content:

`@echo off
python -m robot %*`

Answer (score 3):

Given that downgrading to RF 3.0.2 solved the issue you have possibly had RF 3.1 installed previously.
In RF 3.1 old start-up scripts like `pybot` are removed and it is a backwards incompatible change in RF 3.1.

You can check the [release notes](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/rf-3.1.rst#old-start-up-scripts-like-pybot-are-removed).

> Old start-up scripts like `pybot` are removed
>
> Old start-up scripts `pybot`, `jybot`, `ipybot`, `jyrebot` and `ipyrebot` have
>   been removed in favor of the generic `robot` and `rebot` scripts
>   introduced in Robot Framework 3.0. ([#2818](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2818))