# not getting pybot file after installing robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

not getting pybot file after installing robot framework

I tried installing robot framework with pypi but when I ran the test script with pybot

bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pybot is not recognized as an internal or external command while running from cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53718254/pybot-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-while-running-from-cm)

Answer (score 2):

In the 3.1 release of Robotframework [the pybot script is now removed](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/rf-3.1.rst#old-start-up-scripts-like-pybot-are-removed) - use the generic `robot`/`rebot` tools.

Comment: You can use the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53752593/5889853