# Robotframework Run issue with RIDE

Tags: robotframework

I am very new to Robot framework. When i am running my first test case i am faacing the below PATH issue:

> "command: pybot.bat --argumentfile
>   c:\users\sourav\appdata\local\temp\RIDEqkszgt.d\argfile.txt --listener
>   C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\contrib\testrunner\TestRunnerAgent.py:50389:False
>   C:\Python27\project_2 [Error 2] The system cannot find the file
>   specified"

I have installed Python in C drive (C:\Python27)
I have installed both WXPython and Python version as 32 bit

I created the project in E drive

Enviromnetal variable Path is also set properly. BUT when i am executing the MY First Test case IN RIDE i facing the path issue.

Please help me on this

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have robot framework 3.1 installed.
You can try to downgrade the version of robot framework to 3.0.4.

pip install robotframework==3.0.4

Comment: There is also a solution to keep using robotframework 3.1. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53752593/5889853